# Same user different display name on different site collections in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, user-profile, sitecollection

I have a user let say with login: "domain\bob". I fist created a team site and the display name was "domain\bob" the user has a active user profile. Then I gave the user a display name "Bob B Bobby" in CA and create a portal site. In the portal site the user has "Bob B Bobby" as display name, the profile is also updated. But in the team site the display name is still "domain\bob".

How to I get the team site to update the display name to "Bob B Bobby", and why is it not done by SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a SharePoint Foundation or SharePoint Server installation? If Server - have you enabled the user profile service application.